# How to Insert Confirm Dialog Between Forms.Authentication and ReturnUrl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialog, forms-authentication

I am revamping the authentication system of an ASP.net webforms application (which relies on Forms.Authentication) to limit each user to a single browser session. To support this, I have created a new IHttpModule which uses an application variable to maintain a dictionary that maps userId to sessions, patterned after [this article](http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/limit-session-account.aspx).

All of that is working great, but there is one more component that we want to add: an ok/cancel dialog displayed after login is successful, warning the user that their first session will be closed if they proceed. If they choose to cancel, then we need to interrupt the login process without sending the user to the returnUrl set via Forms.Authentication.

So far, my attempts have been around adding this to the `loggedIn` event, where the sessionId is captured and compared, however my attempts at stopping things once this point occurs have not worked out -- the user is redirected past my confirm dialog without anything actually firing.

Thus the question: **How can I insert a confirm dialog to the login process of Authentication.Forms?**

Comment: Security complications ruled out any type of AJAX intercept-before-the-postback-and-deal-with-it-before-the-Forms.Authentication approach. Since nothing else seemed to work out for interrupting the process, we decided to skip the option for letting the current user stay logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Something you might try - make the form auth an ajax call, then handle your dialog on the client side. So, for example, intercept the login form post using jquery, do an ajax post of the login form, get json or something else back, and then pop the dialog with a redirect on the client side.